# IE Favorites backup tool?

Tags: backup, internet-explorer, bookmarks

Every time I format my PC I forget to backup my IE favorites and lose them all from Internet Explorer.

Is there a tool that automatically makes backup/restore of IE favorites in a chosen location like a network path?

I know that is possible to change default favorites folder location, but that's not what I want to do.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[X Marks](http://www.xmarks.com/) syncs between different browsers and computers and has a permanent backup on a server. You can use multiple profiles (home and office for example) and sync passwords, tabs in addition to favorites if you want.
It's a plugin for Firefox and has versions for IE, Chrome and Safari. I use it to sync favorites between FF and IE on multiple computers without problems. The sync is done on favorites menu and toolbar independent of the browser you use and I just saw it now works on iPhone, iTouch and soon on android.
On Firefox it's fully automatic and on IE it places an icon in the right bottom tray.

Answer (score 0):

No "automatic" way but you can easily use Windows backup to make a backup of the favorites folder in the profile folder( not sure of which Windows you have) and a simple copy and paste will work.

You could use a the USMT to copy the entire profile as well.

You can alos use the Import-Export menu in IE to export the favorites (plus feeds and cookies) to a network location or external drive.

Answer (score 0):

If you want good bookmark backup/syncing Google Chrome does it with your Google account. If you don't mind trying a new browser it's a very easy (and ridiculously useful) solution.

I think Firefox has some extensions to do the same.